# insert value to a list while loop

Tags: python, loops, insert

trying to do simple loop and insert 0 if condition is true, but it not working.

could you please help me to solve this simple issue

Thank you

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
num = 0
for i in a_list:
    if len(str(i)) < 2 :
    a_list.insert(i,num)

print(a_list)

a_list must be [01,02,03]
```

Comment: it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing indentation, it should be like this :

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
num = 0
for i in a_list:
    if len(str(i)) < 2:
        a_list.insert(i,num)

print(a_list)
```

and you are doing wrong in your logic, you should **replace** and not insert element, you should have something like this :

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
num = 0
for i,e in enumerate(a_list):
    if len(str(e)) < 2:
        a_list[i]='0'+str(e);

print(a_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. When you insert into a list, you add an item to a specific position (0 in your case). The output you want is **manipulating** the currect data, i.e change 1 -> 01, 2 -> 02. It's not as same as [0, 1].

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
num = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(a_list):
    if len(str(i)) < 2:
        a_list[idx] = '{:0>2}'.format(i)

print(a_list)  # --> ['01', '02', '03']
```